# How to make the function the most efficient without using max()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am a uni student studying python and I was asked to make the following function shorter and more efficient but the main functionality needs to be saved.
If x is grater than y it should return x, if y is grater than x it should return y, if they are equal it should return None and i need to do that without using the max built in function. Any suggestions?

```
def IsGreater(x,y):
    res=0
    if x>y:
        res=x  
    elif y>x:
        res=y
    return res
```

Comment: There is no way a function will return nothing. If you don't specify a return value, it will return `None` anyway.

Comment: yes, i know,  just meant to say that this code will not work 'couse if x and y are equal it will return one of them and not none.                                                                                 def IsGreater(x,y):
    return x if x > y else y

Comment: "This code will not work" i's unclear. You should always specify very clearly what a function will return - or which exception it will raise - for every possible input it might receive.

Comment: i meant that it will not give the desired results.  this should do it:  def IsGreater(x,y):
    if x!=y:
        return x if x > y else y

Comment: This will return  `None` when x == y. Is that the expected result? If not, then you have to clearly tell us what the function must return in this case.

Comment: yes. i edited the original post so that it will be more clear

Comment: Perfect,that's clear now! :) To make that explicit, you could explicitely `return None` at the end. Note that the answers you received all will return the common value in case of equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun:

```
def is_greater(x, y):
    return [x, y][x < y]
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't even know that is valid syntax.

Comment: awesome. can you tell me where i can find more data about this kind of syntax?

Comment: "Just for fun" should have given you a clue that this is a tongue-in-cheek answer. Never use this in production! You'll drive your colleagues insane.

Now, how this works: `x < y` gives a boolean value. This is coerced to an integer for the index: `true` becomes 1 and `false` becomes 0. And the `[x, y]` before the index is an array with two elements. If you index with 0 you get `x` and with 1 you get `y`. That's all folks.

Comment: Thanks @nalply for explaining (i am obviously too late to the party). For driving your colleagues insane for real one should use [x,y][~y<x]

Comment: @AivarPaalberg  You gonna explain what the result would be?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def IsGreater(x,y):
    return x if x > y else y
```

Comment: but if they are equal it would still return y :-\

Comment: @OshratAraff what do you expect when they are equal? return them both??

Comment: 0 or none so that i can tell that they are equal

Comment: The original code does the same, there is no else branch to return `none`.

Comment: the original code will return 0